# MVC Tag helpers not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tag-helpers

I have an issue with tag helpers. 
All I want to do is create a form that posts data to the controller - basic enough I thought but it doesnt work in my project.

I create a brand new asp.net core web application with default setup and it works there but my project refuses to recognise the tags and act accordingly. 
Notably the markup doesnt highlight the same or provide info when hovered over so some ref or something fundamental is missing, can anyone advise.

*Default project working with correct highlights
[image]

*My project - not highlighting the code right or working. 
Project.json is the exact same so I have no idea whats missing.
[image]

Comment: May be it will help.
Close the project, -> browse project files-> Delete the .suo file from the explorer -> open and check again -- OR -- try to Unload and Reload project again in solution

Comment: Sadly no. I swear I cannot find a single difference for this issue..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

FOUND IT!
Microsoft like to change things. So, MVC 6 (asp.net core ...etc) can make use of a _`ViewImports.cshtml` file in the views folder (feel free to add it yourself if you like me  made a project before this existed).

This acts like global import file, and to make the tag helpers available in all your views, you need to add reference here.

Mine now looks like this:

```
@using Mobile.Models
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

And boom - tags look correct and its work as expected.

Comment: Nice Find!  I think this happened to me because I imported a bunch of views from another project.  Non-the-less this did the trick!  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You will also face this issue  when you create a new Area in the asp.net core MVC project, to resolve it copy `~/Views/_ViewImports.cshtml` to `~/AreaName/Views/_ViewImports.cshtml`

Comment: While this works, it can also be solved by simply moving the `_ViewImports.cshtml` to the root directory of the application (next to Program.cs so to speak).

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you MUST specify the assembly name and not the namespace.
That was my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add my solution for this situation. I copied the lines in _ViewImport, then deleted and recreated this file and it worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).